# Error while uploading file from Android to Node Server "Permission denied"

Tags: android, file, http

I am trying to use an Android app to upload a file to a node js server on my laptop. While it works fine with html, when trying to do the same in Andorid I get the following error. 
The server is a simple Node server which seems to be working fine when I use other methods of posting files.

```
Error in upload with ID: 10ff84ba-0768-4423-a955-7a1a4f68d1aa. /init.rc: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /init.rc: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadFile.getStream(BinaryUploadFile.java:34)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadTask.writeBody(BinaryUploadTask.java:29)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.upload(HttpUploadTask.java:131)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.run(HttpUploadTask.java:65)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:127)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadFile.getStream(BinaryUploadFile.java:34) 
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadTask.writeBody(BinaryUploadTask.java:29) 
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.upload(HttpUploadTask.java:131) 
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.run(HttpUploadTask.java:65) 
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:127) 
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
01-01 08:17:17.382 20517-25217/jorc.com.fileupload2 W/com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadTask: Error in uploadId 5d59b0bb-5f5f-4926-b17d-87a8e408af4f on attempt 1. Waiting 1s before next attempt java.io.FileNotFoundException: /init.rc: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadFile.getStream(BinaryUploadFile.java:34)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.BinaryUploadTask.writeBody(BinaryUploadTask.java:29)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.upload(HttpUploadTask.java:131)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.run(HttpUploadTask.java:65)
at com.alexbbb.uploadservice.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:127)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

[image]

Trying later I get the following confirmation from logcat but still no file is uploaded to my server:

```
01-01 08:57:43.032 1837-1837/jorc.com.fileupload2 I/UploadServiceDemo: Upload with ID 2b47d6b5-7bf6-4cf0-aeec-462b20c40ffd is completed: 200, <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                                       <html>
                                                                       <head>
                                                                         <title>File Uploader</title>
                                                                         <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                                                       </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using this repo from githib:
https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service
in this case go to MainActivity.java file and add

```
.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "your_key")
.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "your_key2")
```

under

```
.addHeader("file-name", new File(fileToUploadPath).getName())
```

That's all you need to see your file being uploaded to parse.com.

To make it easier on device add this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
     alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
     alertDialog.setMessage(serverResponseMessage);
     alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
       }
     });
alertDialog.show();
```

Under this which shows you the uploaded file URL.

```
public void onCompleted(String uploadId, int serverResponseCode, String serverResponseMessage) {
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly written in your `logcat` Permission denied, you need to give READ permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I added the appapp permission below the question.